# Playing audio from a selected table cell stored in an array created from a Struct

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, audio-player

I have a list of ambient sounds displayed in a table, when you click one it takes you to a second view controller which shows the sound title, shows an image and gives a description of the ambient sound and displays a play button, I've all the data in an array from a Struct but having problems getting the audio to play, here is an example my code:

My Struct:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Foundation

struct Audio {
    var title: String
    var imageName: UIImage
    var descr: String
    var audioURL: String
}
```

My View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let audios = [Audio(title: "Bubbling Pools", imageName: UIImage(named: ("1.png"))!, descr: "The stench of life fills the air. Viscous fluid bubbles to the surface in great exhortations of gas and moisture. Something about these pools is familiar..", audioURL: "2_Bubbling_Pools.mp3"),
                  Audio(title: "March Of Faith", imageName: UIImage(named: ("2.png"))!, descr: "The devoted stream into the distance. The dust from their sandaled feet blocks out the sun for miles around. There's no stopping them. They believe.", audioURL: "3_The_March_of_the_Faithful.mp3"),
                  Audio(title: "Solemn Vow", imageName: UIImage(named: ("3.png"))!, descr: "When death is near, and retreat is not an option. Only the bravest have any purchase on the word \"honor\".", audioURL: "4_Solemn_Vow-a.mp3")

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return audios.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let audio = audios[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = audio.title

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let audio = audios[indexPath.row]

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: audio)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue" {

            let audio = sender as! Audio
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            destinationVC.selectedAudio = audio
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

}
```

My Second View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var artworkImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!

    var selectedAudio: Audio!

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        titleLabel.text = selectedAudio.title
        artworkImage.image = selectedAudio.imageName
        descriptionLabel.text = selectedAudio.descr

    }

    @IBAction func playButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        playAudio()

    }

    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    func playAudio() {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: selectedAudio.audioURL, withExtension: "mp3")!

        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            guard let player = player else { return }

            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you get to the point where player.play() is called (make sure via output or breakpoint)?

Comment: Connected to the above: have you made sure that the url is what you like (seems problematic to just use filenames) and that the files do actually exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting `.mp3` from the URLs in `audios`. `URLForResource:withExtension:` takes the extension separately.